# Python wordpress xmlrpc -32700 error with wordpress4.8

Tags: php, python, wordpress, ubuntu

I just built a wordpress site and used the latest version (4.8.3).
I want to use `python-wordpress-xmlrpc` module. It used to works before, but now when I use QuickStart guide to connect to my wordpress, it shows an erorr.

I googled it for two day, but didn't get any answers. I found an issue on module creator's github:
https://github.com/maxcutler/python-wordpress-xmlrpc/issues/110

Looks like some people have the same error.

This is my code:

```py
host = 'http://sample.com'
wp = Client(host+'/xmlrpc.php', 'root', 'password')
print(wp)
r = wp.call(GetPosts())

#Error:
 MEssage xmlrpc.client.Fault: <Fault -32700: 'parse error. not well formed'>
```

I think maybe it's because wordpress 4.8 uses php7 that I get errors.
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Have any of the answers helped you resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience with the -32700 error showed up when trying to use python 3, wordpress REST API and wordpress_xmlrpc python package.

When using the REST API the read functions all worked with pycurl. However, the authentication was a problem.

I moved to using wordpress_xmlrpc to solve the logon/handshake method. This worked well with my development/test wordpress instance but failed miserably when I moved to the QA site (fully copy of production).

In QA I kept receiving a -32700 xmlrpc python wordpress parse error. Very specific message with no real insight into what caused the problem. Searching "-32700 xmlrpc wordpress rest api python" gave many results, but few that actually helped. After trying numerous things here is the what actually helped.

**Turn on Debugging in WordPress.**

In wp-config.php there was a line:

`define('WP_DEBUG', false);`

To turn on debugging you need to change this to:

`define('WP_DEBUG', true);`

and then add the line:

`define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);`

Once this is in place you run your program it will produce an error that shows up in wp-content/debug.log. My error showed:

`[10-Apr-2018 16:53:30 UTC] PHP Notice:  PHP's XML extension is not available. Please contact your hosting provider to enable PHP's XML extension. in /home/cqinfo/www-wordpress/wp-includes/IXR/class-IXR-message.php on line 48`

From here it was rather simple to solve. I had my admin install the PHP XML extension. AND RESTART apache.

Hope this helps others solve the mystery of the -32700 error for others.

We use this to populate a weekly news clipping that has our own thoughts on what is going on in the world of AI and Machine learning at CloudQuant.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like PHP XML extension is not installed on the server.

Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install php-xml

sudo service apache2 restart
```

This resolved the issue in my case.

Comment: Thanks!!! In my installation I had to run: sudo apt-get install php7.4-xml

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
from wordpress_xmlrpc import Client, WordPressPost
from wordpress_xmlrpc.methods import posts

host = 'http://sample.com'
wp = Client(host+'/xmlrpc.php', 'root', 'password')
r = wp.call(posts.GetPosts())
```